# MATLAB: Comparing 2 arrays with different lengths

Tags: arrays, matlab, size, match, sampling

I have two arrays with different lengths (due to different sampling rates) that I need to compare. I'd like to downsample the larger array to match the smaller one in length, however the factor is not an integer but a decimal.

For an example:

```
a =
     1     1.375     1.75     2.125     2.5     2.875     3.25

b =
     1     2     3
```

Is there any way to manipulate these arrays to match lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy to do with clever use of [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).  The trick is that the keypoints used for interpolation is an array going from 1 up to as many values as you have in `a` which we will call `N`, and the interpolated keypoints would be a linearly increasing array where the first point is 1, the last point is `N` and you evenly divide up this range to have as many points as there are in `b`.

Simply put:

```
anew = interp1(1:numel(a), a, linspace(1, N, numel(b)));
```

[`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) generates a linearly increasing array from 1 to `N = numel(a)` for as many points as you want, which we determine as the total number of elements in `b`.  This exactly specifies the right keypoints you want to give you a downsampled version of `a` that matches the length of `b`, though there will be some interpolation required.  The default interpolation method is linear.

Using the sample input from `a` you provided, we get:

```
>> anew

anew =

    1.0000    2.1250    3.2500
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much **rayryeng**.

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck!